# Как вернуть с помощью ajax запросов несколько параметров в формате JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, битрикс

Написал функцию которая по клику кнопки ajax запросом обращается к файлу и вытягивает из него результат в формате json. Это либо `result: fail` либо `result: success`. Со временем задача стала сложнее и теперь необходимо вытягивать несколько результатов одним запросом и по ним делать несколько условий (в примере указано одно условие). Как это осуществить?

```js
//Функция обработчик кнопки
function butt() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'phpOsago.php',
            data: $('.passegAdd').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(json);
                if (json.result === 'success') {
                    document.getElementById("sex").style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("sex").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    $('#00015NUMBEROSAGO').removeClass('rfield');
                    $('#from1').removeClass('rfield');
                    $('#to1').removeClass('rfield');
                    $('#fileOSAGO').removeClass('rfield');
                }

            }

        });
        return true;
    }
```

```js
//phpOsago.php Ajax запросом обращаемся к нему

$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO", "PROPERTY_OWNER_AUTO", "PROPERTY_DOGOVOR_ARENDI", "PROPERTY_DATE_NUMBER");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => "3", "ACTIVE" => "Y", "ID"=> $_POST["99999company"]);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize" => 300), $arSelect);

while ($ob = $res->Fetch()) {
   $result[] = $ob["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"];
   $result[] = $ob["PROPERTY_OWNER_AUTO_VALUE"];
   $result[] = $ob["PROPERTY_DOGOVOR_ARENDI_VALUE"];
}

if($result[0]["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"] == "1"){

    $response = '{"result": "success"}';
    echo json_encode($response);

}else{
    $response = '{"result": "fail"}';
    echo json_encode($response);
}

if($result[1]["PROPERTY_OWNER_AUTO_VALUE"] == "1"){

    $response1 = '{"result1": "success1"}';
    echo json_encode($response1);

}else{
    $response1 = '{"result1": "fail1"}';
    echo json_encode($response1);
}

if($result[2]["PROPERTY_DOGOVOR_ARENDI_VALUE"] == "1"){

    $response2 = '{"result2": "success2"}';
    echo json_encode($response2);

}else{
    $response2 = '{"result2": "fail2"}';
    echo json_encode($response2);
}
```

Comment: В `json_encode` у аргумента тип `mixed`, поэтому можно передать заранее созданный объект, массив и т.д. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @XelaNimed а как мне передать одним массивом полученные результаты условий?

Comment: А нельзя в цикле `while` сделать так `$response = json_encode($ob)`  и затем вывести его `echo $response` вместо кучи условий?

Comment: @XelaNimed условия то полюбому же нужны, проверяется наличие значения 1 или 0 у переменной.

Comment: Ну а почему бы это не интерпретировать на стороне клиента? А так запутаться можно в `result1,2,3,n`. Имена возвращаемых результатов Вам не будут ни о чём говорить на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю следующую схему
файл-обработчик phpOsago.php

```
<?php
define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NO_AGENT_STATISTIC", true);
define("NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS", true);

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

$context = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getContext();

$response = new \Bitrix\Main\HttpResponse($context);
$response->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

$request = $context->getRequest();
$request->addFilter(new Bitrix\Main\Web\PostDecodeFilter);

if ($result[0]["PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE"] == "1"){
    $arResult['PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE'] = [
        'result' => 'success'
    ];
}else{
    $arResult['PROPERTY_NEED_OSAGO_VALUE'] = [
        'result' => 'fail'
    ];
}

if($result[2]["PROPERTY_DOGOVOR_ARENDI_VALUE"] == "1"){

     $arResult['PROPERTY_DOGOVOR_ARENDI_VALUE'] = [
        'result' => 'success'
    ];

}else{
     $arResult['PROPERTY_DOGOVOR_ARENDI_VALUE'] = [
        'result' => 'fail'
    ];
}

// возвращаем результат
$response->flush(Bitrix\Main\Web\Json::encode($arResult));
```